# Unable to import PIL into project

Tags: python, import, module, python-imaging-library

The PIL module should be installed because when I run the `pip install pillow` I get this message: `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in [my installation route]`. But, when I try to import this into a file, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

this has worked for me if your using vscode try install by typing `py -m pip install pillow`

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
```

Comment: I import using from PIL import Image and I've tried from PIL import * as you sugested too, but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Pillow is a fork of PIL, and the import is carried over.

```
import PIL
```

Should do the trick. The documentation has additional details:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html